# Usar unity sin resolver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de utilizar unity con la configuración de sus registros en una librería externa y esta sea adicionada a mi proyecto web o consola, y cuando los controladores del proyecto reciban una interfaz como parámetros sean resueltos.

La idea es que no quiero usar `Unity.MVC` por que me estaría casando con una capa de presentación. Sino hacer algo genérico sea cual sea el tipo de aplicación en la presentación.

Comment: @KristianDamian por favor no edites las preguntas para colocar etiquetas allí. Por favor revisa [¿Qué formato deberían tener los nombres de tecnologías/lenguajes?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/448/227)

Answer (score 1):

Como todas estas librerias son de código abierta podrias analizar el código que se encuentra en [el repositorio de GitHub de Unity.Mvc5](https://github.com/devtrends/Unity.Mvc5) y estudiar cómo lo implementan para poder adaptarlo a tu necesidad. De esta forma copias el código sin tener una dependencia a la libreria.

La definición del `UnityContainer` y los registros de los tipos puedes realizarlos en una librería separada

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IxxService, xxService>();
```

Pero el punto importante es cómo defines el `DependencyResolver`

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

Cuando usas una implementación propia, pero es en ese punto donde ayuda `Unity.Mvc`

[[ASP.NET MVC] Inyectando dependencias con Microsoft Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn593716.aspx)